# Is it possible to look up or determine nominal operating temperatures for various processors?

Tags: cpu, temperature, monitoring

I am tweaking icinga checks for my servers, one of the checks is monitoring CPU temperatures. Problem is that each CPU has different operating temperatures T_MAX etc. where it should actually show some alert.

In my case it's these CPU:

- Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1230 v6 @ 3.50GHz
- Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1220 v3 @ 3.10GHz
- Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1230 v5 @ 3.40GHz

I was looking at intel ARK website, which contains various parameters, but none of these specify optimal temperatures, or T_MAX

Is there any database that contains such information or any place where this can be looked up?

Comment: ARK website is the database

Answer (score 1):

You can find what you're looking for in [Intel's technical resources](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/xeon/xeon-technical-resources.html) for your Xeon chips.

- Find the section that pertains to your particular processor. In your case `Intel® Xeon® Processor E3 Family`
- Find the subsection for each separate type: Intel® Xeon® processor E3-1200 v3 product family, Intel® Xeon® processor E3-1200 v5 product family, and Intel® Xeon® processor E3-1200 v6 product family.
- Under `Technical Documents`, Open up the `Datasheet, Volume 1`. That's where the TJMax values are written under `Junction Specifications` along with a host of other useful information regarding thermals.

To speed things up, in chrome I used Find (Ctrl + F) and entered in `°C`. You can then easily find the sections containing thermal values.

Comment: I will expand your answer a bit, after searching in these documents I couldn't find precise value - it actually seems each single CPU is unique and has own TjMAX factory calibrated when testing, from intel datasheet: `TjMAX is factory calibrated and is not user configurable. The default value is software visible in the TEMPERATURE_TARGET (0x1A2) MSR, bits [23:16]`

Comment: it would be interesting to know how to obtain that `TEMPERATURE_TARGET (0x1A2) MSR, bits [23:16]` via some software (preferably Linux) I have no idea, it's not in dmi dump